# PostgreSQL unique index for a specific set of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say there is a table AVATARS and among other columns it has `user_id` (foreign key to users table) and `state` where state can be any value from 0 to 6. I want to create a constraint so that user can have only 2 avatars, where one has state = 0 and the other has any state != 0. I wonder if it's possible to implement with a unique index? Or I am gonna have to add some boolean column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a unique index with an expression:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX avatars_userid_state_0_idx ON avatars(user_id,(state<>0));
```

(or `state = 0`, the end result is the same).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using filtered unique indexes.

For one value with state = 0:

```
create unique index unq_avatars_user_state0
    on avatars(user_id, state)
    where state = 0;
```

For one value with state <> 0:

```
create unique index unq_avatars_user_state0
    on avatars(user_id, state)
    where state <> 0;
```

Note:  these do not guarantee that such values exist, just that there is at most one of each them.